# filling in one text file with values from another text file

Tags: c, arrays, loops, readfile

I have the following text file results.txt:

```
x y  u  v
3 2 10 12
3 3 10 15
3 4 11 15
5 1 10 12
5 2 12 13
5 3 9 9
```

Now I want to take the values u and v from the above file and put them into another file where x goes from 2 to 5 and y goes from 1 to 5 so I can get the desired output:

```
2 1 
2 2
2 3
2 4
2 5
3 1
3 2 10 12
3 3 10 15
3 4 11 15
3 5
4 1
4 2
4 3
4 4
4 5
5 1 10 12
5 2 12 13
5 3
5 4
5 5
```

For generating the x and y values in the above output I just use a loop as shown below:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {

    float lat,lon;
    int count;

    count=1;

    for ( lat = -70; lat <= 80; lat = lat + .125){
        for ( lon = -179.875; lon <= 180; lon = lon + 0.125){
            printf("%d) Value of lat/lon: %0.2f/%0.2f\n", count,lat,lon);
            count=count+1;
            if (xx= x && yy = y){
                 printf("%d %d %f %f\n",xx,yy,u,v)
            }
            else
            {
                 printf("%d %d\n",x,y)

            }       
        }
    }
```

}

In the context of the above c program snippet, how do I do I read the file results.txt along with the above loop so that when the x and y values combinations from the above loop match the x and y combinations in results.txt (xx and yy) inserts it prints the corresponding line from the results.txt file?  How do I tweak the above program with the appropriate read statements to get the desired output results?

Comment: Are you familiar with containers, such as arrays? It looks as if you are attempting something too far beyond your ability to be a useful exercise.

Comment: I know I have to read the data from the results.txt into an array put the issue is parsing the lines from that file into x,y,u and v.

Comment: I was able to do this in perl but the processing time for large files can take a long time.

Comment: Use comparisons `==` and not assignments `=` in conditions: `if (xx= x && yy = y){` is wrong.

Comment: Your example code bears no relation to the example data.  The example data is relatively straight-forward; you create an in-memory record of the data in the `results.txt` file (array, list, other structure? I'll assume an array), and then as you're reading the data from the other file, lookup the entry in the array and print the appropriate data.  It is harder if you're dealing with float indexes (and `lat` and `lon` in the code suggest that you are).  You can't do fractional indexes in an array (so you can't lookup using `lat` and `lon` as the indexes).  You can still search an array.

Comment: `fscanf(fp, "%d %d %d %d", &x, &y, %u, %v);` What's the problem?

Comment: You missed `5 3 9 9`  in the output file.

Comment: the posted code causes the compiler to output several 'error' messages.  How can you expect us to advise you when you have not posted code that cleanly compiles?

Comment: when compiling, always enable all the warnings, then fix those warnings.  (for `gcc`, at a minimum use: `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic`  I also use: `-Wconversion -std=gnu11` ).   Amongst other things, this line: `printf("%d %d %f %f\n",xx,yy,u,v)` refers to variable `v` and `u` but those variable do not exist AND the line is missing a trailing semicolon `;`.   Similar missing semicolon for: `printf("%d %d\n",x,y)`

Comment: for ease of readability and understanding: 1) follow the axiom: *only statement per line and (at most) one variable declaration per statement.*  2) separate code blocks (for, if, else, while, do...while, switch, case, default) via a single blank line.

Comment: the variables: `x`, `xx`, `y`, `yy` are not declared

Comment: the variables: `lat` and `lon` are declared as `float`, so all literals being assigned to them should also be declared `float`.  I.E. the literals need a decimal point AND a trailing `f`.   With no decimal point, the value is an `int`.  With no trailing `f` the value is a `double`,

Comment: it is a poor programming practice to `#include` header files those contents are not being used in the code

Comment: did someone replace the actual OPs code with some silliness?  The question has nothing to do with the 'currently' posted code.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, let me tell you I didn't understand what do you want to do with your example code. It seems that it has no connection with your question:

> filling in one text file with values from another text file

If you already have the filled `results.txt` and you wish to fill the second file (let call it `second.txt`) as you defined, then you can do it as follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    FILE* fp;
    int x, y, i;
    char found = 0;

    int results[1024][4] = {};
    int rows = 0;

    /* Open the results.txt for read. */
    fp = fopen("results.txt", "r");
    if(fp == NULL)
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);

    /* Parse results.txt line-by-line and store the values to results array. */
    while(fscanf(fp, "%d %d %d %d\n",
            &results[rows][0], &results[rows][1],
            &results[rows][2], &results[rows][3]) == 4 && rows < 1024) {
        printf("x: %d, y: %d, u: %d, v: %d\n", results[rows][0],
                results[rows][1], results[rows][2], results[rows][3]);
        rows++;
    }

    fclose(fp);

    /* Open the second.txt for write. */
    fp = fopen("second.txt", "w");
    if(fp == NULL)
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);

    for(x = 2; x <= 5; ++x) {
        for(y = 1; y <= 5; ++y) {
            found = 0;

            /* Search for matching entry in results array. */
            for(i = 0; i < rows; ++i) {
                if(results[i][0] == x && results[i][1] == y) {
                    found = 1;
                    break;
                }
            }

            if(found)
                fprintf(fp, "%d %d %d %d\n", x, y, results[i][2], results[i][3]);
            else
                fprintf(fp, "%d %d\n", x, y);
        }
    }

    fclose(fp);
    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

The example above is not optimized but tested and works. It is limited to maximal 1024 lines in `results.txt`.